# Export .asc file from QGIS to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, qgis, geoserver

I've got a .asc file I want to put into my postgres database and later publish it with Geoserver. I wasn't able to directly load the file into my database, so now I'm using QGIS and the export function.
My problem is that since I'm not very familiar with QGIS and geodata in general, I don't know what file format to save my layer to then export it in the next step. Where do I save my layer with the appropriate file format, so I can export it?

[image: QGIS view]

Comment: You don't need to convert it, please have a look on https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html. You have to have PostGIS installed over PostgreSQL.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I tried using raster2pgsql initially, however it ended up with me being unable to look at my database tables for some reason and a ton of runtime exceptions in geoserver when trying to publish the layer

Comment: You want to convert it to a geotif and there's no need to put it in the database, geoserver will serve it directly